# Remove Office from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365

How do I completely remove Office and it's occasional "offer" from Windows 10? I have never explicitly or implicitly installed it.

[image: Office on Windows 10]

Comment: Readily found on the web: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Don't hurt yourself too much falling from that high horse and all those presumptions. This window randomly would appear when returning to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I held `Shift` when pressing the Start key and used Microsoft's version of the Start Menu.
2. I typed "Office".
3. An 'Uninstall' option was available for the "app".

Comment: Shift? This seems like you're using some Start Menu replacement as there is no functionality like that in Windows 10.

Comment: @John Based on your picture above, it is an app for [Office online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY1Q3.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

1. Just click on the not needed Office in start menu with the **right mouse button** and select "Uninstall".
2. On a new PC for example in Europe, multiple language versions may be installed - uninstall them in "Start / Settings / Apps".

[image: context menu]